# ¿Cómo hacer summarise de vectores caracter o factor en R con dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by, table, dplyr, summarise

Tengo el siguiente data frame.

```
set.seed(2021)
df<-data.frame(SEXO=sample(c("M","F"),20,T),
               AÑOS=sample(1:30,20,T))

df
   SEXO AÑOS
1     M   28
2     F   18
3     F   27
4     F   28
5     M   29
6     F    3
7     F   14
8     F    8
9     F   26
10    F    4
11    M    5
12    F   22
13    F   16
14    M    2
15    M   19
16    M    4
17    M   21
18    M   22
19    F    5
20    M    9
```

Lo que deseo es calcular las frecuencias y las frecuencias relativas de la variable `SEXO`.
Lo he hecho de esta manera.

```
df %>% mutate(N=n()) %>% group_by(SEXO) %>% 
  summarise(n=n(),p=n()/unique(N))
```

Lo que me resulta lo deseado.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SEXO      n     p
  <chr> <int> <dbl>
1 F        11  0.55
2 M         9  0.45
```

Pero es obvio que es mucho código. Porque le doy mucha vuelta.

Cual sería la forma más eficiente de encontrar lo anterior, usando `dplyr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df %>%  
  count(SEXO) %>%  
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

  SEXO  n prop
1    F 11 0.55
2    M  9 0.45
```

No sé si es más eficiente, pero es un poco más corto.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para el que este interesados en proporciones mostrando porcentajes:

```
df %>%
  group_by (SEXO) %>%
  summarise (n=n()) %>%
  mutate(rel.freq = paste0(round(100 * n/sum(n), 0), "%"))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SEXO      n rel.freq
  <chr> <int> <chr>   
1 F        11 55%     
2 M         9 45%
```